# Instagram story in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a image that can set text over it, and should be save image and text in remote server(text can be drag on image), when fetch image should be click on text(like instagram story).
[image]
how to save it on database?

Comment: Try using this package: story_view: ^0.14.0 - https://pub.dev/packages/story_view

Comment: my problem is save image with text, not view story

Answer (score 0):

you can send you text to the database before the story duration end or when the store starts

that means:

here you have a function to load the story inside the function you can make the story load with await then check if the story has text

write a query to send it to DB

if not do nothing